# How to create a Tappable Text Fragment with a Popover, like in the Duolingo App?

Tags: swiftui

In a SwiftUI App, how do I show a paragraph of text, where some fragments of text are tappable, and tapping on them opens a popover view, just like how it is for the Duolingo App? See screenshot below.

[image: Duolingo]

Comment: SwiftUI doesn't support this easily there are a ton of solutions that might work such as a "Flow Layout".

Comment: can you give me some pointers?

Comment: Search for Flow Layout

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @lorem ipsum for the tip. I got it to work using https://github.com/globulus/swiftui-flow-layout and popover.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIFlowLayout

struct TappableTextFragment: View {
    let text: String
    @State private var showPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
          .font(.system(size: 12))
          .underline(true, pattern: .dot)
          .onTapGesture {
              showPopover = true
          }
          .popover(isPresented: $showPopover, content: {
              Text(text)
                  .padding()
                  .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
          })
    }
}

struct TappableParagraph: View {
    
    let items = [
        "Some long item here",
        "And then some longer one",
        "Short",
        "Items",
        "Here",
        "And",
        "A",
        "Few",
        "More",
        "And then a very very very long one"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        FlowLayout(mode: .scrollable, items: items, itemSpacing: 3) {
            TappableTextFragment(text: $0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    TappableParagraph()
}
```